Why is Apple Magic Trackpad 3 not working with Linux Mint 21.1?
I bought an Apple Magic Trackpad 3.
On my Linux Mint, when connecting the lightning cable to the USB-C port of my computer, it shows in dmesg:
[ 5634.954696] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=0265, bcdDevice= 8.60
[ 5634.954701] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5634.954702] usb 1-2: Product: Magic Trackpad
[ 5634.954704] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[ 5634.954705] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: CC2412200FK1G2QBM
[ 5634.966468] magicmouse 0003:05AC:0265.0019: fixing up magicmouse battery report descriptor
[ 5634.966558] input: Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:05AC:0265.0019/input/input45
[ 5634.966819] magicmouse 0003:05AC:0265.0019: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[ 5634.967876] input: Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:05AC:0265.001A/input/input46
[ 5634.967991] magicmouse 0003:05AC:0265.001A: input,hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[ 5634.969153] magicmouse 0003:05AC:0265.001B: hiddev2,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
[ 5634.970108] magicmouse 0003:05AC:0265.001C: hiddev3,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input3
[ 5776.951075] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
0 min

It also shows in xinput:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Usb KeyBoard Usb KeyBoard Consumer Control        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:01 06CB:CE2D Mouse               id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:01 06CB:CE2D Touchpad            id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ input-remapper mouse                      id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]

It does not show when I try to pair it via Bluetooth, nor does it work as a mouse via the USB-C cable. I'd be happy with either
(Also note that the box says Magic Trackpad 3, but xinput says Magic Trackpad 2)
Any hints/next steps?

https://superuser.com/questions/1705684/does-the-apple-magic-trackpad-2-work-on-linux

You are correct, giacomo. Those instructions work. I am ok with question closing
